# Problem: "npm ERR! cb() never called! npm ERR! not ok code 0" when installing etherpad

Tags: nodejs

on an Ubuntu 12.04.3:

```
adduser --system --home=/var/www/etherpad --group etherpad

apt-get install gzip git-core curl python libssl-dev build-essential abiword python-software-properties

add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
apt-get update; apt-get install -y nodejs

su - etherpad -s /bin/bash
git clone git://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite.git
cd etherpad-lite
sed -i 's/bin\/installDeps.sh/sh bin\/installDeps.sh/g' bin/run.sh
sh bin/run.sh
```

but when using sh bin/run.sh:

```
Ensure that all dependencies are up to date...  If this is the first time you have run Etherpad please be patient.
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**Q:** How can I resolve this problem? "npm cache clear didn't" helped. The FS is mounted with noexec. System is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

For those seeing this 2013-09-27, there's an [bug](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2907) with the latest release of `npm`. Downgrading `nodejs` to `0.10.17` seems to solve the issue.

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393821/npm-err-cb-never-called)

Answer (score 0):

`npm shrinkwrap` and then `npm install` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

It has been fixed in 0.10.20:
http://ghost.org/forum/installation/353-npm-err-cb-never-called